# Bundling an extension and packaged app together

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a packaged app that requires a page action, so I created an extension to communicate with my base app. When it comes time to distribution, is there anyway to bundle an app and extension together so users don't have to install two .crxs?

If not, is it possible to add dependencies to extensions?

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify: you have two separate .crx files and your packaged app is also a chrome extension? Is it possible for you to make the other app one of the 'content_scripts;?

Comment: @tristan packaged apps are not permitted to have page actions which is why I had to resort to splitting it up into an extension and a packaged app. So yes, two separate crx files but one is a packaged app and one is a chrome extension.